# How do I scrape data from this specific website?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get some data out of this website.

http://asphaltoilmarket.com/index.php/state-index-tracker/

I am trying to get the data using the following code but it times out.

```
   import requests
   asphalt_r = requests.get('http://asphaltoilmarket.com/index.php/state-index-tracker/')
```

This website opens with no problems in the browser and also I can get data from other websites (with different structure) using this code, but my code does not work with this website. I am not sure what changes I need to make.

Also, I could get the data to download in excel and  another tool (Alteryx) which uses GET from curl.

Comment: If you want to downvote, please suggest edit or any recommendation.

Comment: There are too many reasons why it can be failed.  I advice you to use contact form on the website, also would be good if you provide information why do you need this information, what if you are planning some bad things? :)

Comment: I have tried curl from "powershell" it is working, maybe you can try to use another library instead of `requests`

Comment: Yes, I have tried curl in another tool and its working there. I need help in getting it to work in python. can you suggest other libraries ?

Comment: I am not working with python, but fast google provides this option http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

They likely don't want you to scrape their site.
The response code is a quick indication of that.

```
>>> import requests
>>> asphalt_r = requests.get('http://asphaltoilmarket.com/index.php/state-index-tracker/')
>>> asphalt_r
<Response [406]>
```

406 = Not Acceptable

```
>>> asphalt_r = requests.get('http://asphaltoilmarket.com/index.php/state-index-tracker/', headers={"User-Agent": "curl/7.54"})
>>> asphalt_r
<Response [200]>
```

Read and follow their AUP & Terms of Service.

Working does not equal permission.

Comment: They are letting their website to be scapped. I could do it using excel, Alteryx and R. but I need help to get it working in python.